# Resizing UIDatePicker with NSContraints

Tags: ios, resize, uidatepicker, autolayout

I am moving to Autolayout and I am stuck among other things to resizing an UIDataPicker, previously done by setting its frame.
I tried:

```
    NSLayoutConstraint *pickerWidthConstraint= [NSLayoutConstraint  constraintWithItem:datePicker attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:150];
    pickerWidthConstraint.priority=400;
    [self addConstraint:pickerWidthConstraint];
```

But it seems not to take care: Considering I moved to autolayout properly to display that datePicker at its best in its backdrop, it would not be very nice if Autolayout did not allow it.

IN particular adding the constraint to the UIDataPicker itself crashes the app:

```
    [datePicker addConstraint:pickerCenterYConstraint];
```

Yet, strangely, if I do it on IB the UIDatePicker resizes smoothly with Autolayout.

Where is the catch?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue seems not to relate to the UIDatePicker, but rather to some conflicting constraints that XCode keeps quite hidden instead of displaying them in the log.

Comment: What is strange is that ALL constraints for the UDatePicker produce a conflict. I tried removing one by one and only when all of them where gone the app stopped crashing. Moreover I am puzzled at receiving none of the expected verbose information in the logs. Is there a way to enable them?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently fixed it, but for the lack of a log. The constraints are always to be set on including views, not on the object, for some strange reason.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the issue is about the recipient of the constraint, apparently it may not be the UIDatePicker. Using UIView it worked just fine, but for the persistent impossibility of lowering the top view.